# Inserting radio button input in the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a quiz-like structure. For that i'm trying to get the answer of each question and insert it into my database with the type of question that was answered. However i'm having trouble putting these data in variables and i'm getting:
Notice: `Undefined index: question-0-answer`

in the commented part of the code. Any help..

```
$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select afnumber from employees WHERE Status='Employed '");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
    $options .="<option >" . $row['afnumber'] . "</option>";
}
$menu="<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
AFNumber : <select name='SelectAF' id='filter' style='color:grey;'>" . $options . "</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Evaluation Test Type : <select name='Type' id='type' style='color:grey;'><option selected='selected'></option><option value='loyalty'>Loyalty</option><option value='performance'>Performance</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type='submit' name='submit1' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>
</form>
<br>
";
 echo $menu;

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))

{   
$type = $_POST['Type'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "Js", "jr");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

 if ( $result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT questiontext FROM questioninfo WHERE type='$type'" ) ) {


        $html=array();

        $html[]="
        <form action='' method='post' id='quiz'>
            <ol>";

        $counter=1;

        while( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {


            $question=$row['questiontext'];
            $answerA=1;
            $answerB=2;
            $answerC=3;
            $answerD=4;
            $answerE=5;

            $html[]="
             <br/>
                <h3>Question {$counter}:&nbsp; {$question}</h3>

                <li>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answersA' value='A' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-A'> {$answerA} </label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answersB' value='B' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-B'> {$answerB} </label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answersC' value='c' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-C'> {$answerC} </label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answersD' value='D' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-D'> {$answerD} </label>
                    <br/>
                    <input type='radio' name='question-{$counter}-answers' id='question-{$counter}-answersE' value='E' />
                    <label for='question-{$counter}-answers-E'> {$answerE} </label>

                </li>";

            $counter++;

        }

        $html[]="
            </ol>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>
        <input type='hidden' name='type' value='{$type}' />
        </form>";

        echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );



    $result->close();

 }
}
/*
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){ 


$numQuestions=10;

for( $counter=0; $counter < $numQuestions; $counter++ ){ 
$answer=$_POST['question-'.$counter.'-answers']; 
$sql="insert into `question` (`type`,`value`) values ('".$type."','".$answer."')"; 
$db->query( $sql ); 
} 
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$counter` for outputting the radiobuttons is initialized with the value `1` but when reading the values of radiobuttons at the end of your script, you are starting with `$counter = 0;`.

Please change

```
for( $counter=0; $counter < $numQuestions; $counter++ ){
```

to

```
for( $counter=1; $counter <= $numQuestions; $counter++ ){
```

Comment: that made the error disappear, however i got Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on boolean on $db->query( $sql );

Comment: You have to use `$mysqli` instead of `$db` - Please change `$db->query($sql)` to `$mysqli->query($sql)`.

Comment: But please take note of @Disha 's answer. It not a good idea to statically access 10 questions of your `$_POST` array. You have to get the amount of questions in your database first and then iterate over `n` questions.

Comment: how do you suggest me doing this?

Comment: Use something like `$mysqli->query( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questioninfo WHERE type='$type'")`, fetch the result and assign `$row['COUNT(*)']` to `$numQuestions`.

Answer (score 0):

You are running loop statically 10 times in comment and what if database have less than 10 records? You need to run loop a many times as db having records or you can put condition before `insert` by `isset($_POST['question-'.$counter.'-answers'])`